# What are the better options to implement Category/Sub Category with paging in MVC4.0?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement, that I have to implement the *Paging* and the Current Page records.
The record are categorized in *Category* and *Sub Category* as mentioned below.

If 
you pay attention to the screenshot, I have to show category as well as Sub Category for the current page pragmatically. Right now, this is a static page.

Do we have any inbuilt feature/Nuget that helps to accomplish this thing quickly in MVC4.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly this isn't as bad as you think it will be to implement. I usually build a input model that looks like this.

```
 public class SearchModel {
      public string Query {get;set;}
      public string Sort {get;set;}
      public string Category {get;set;}
      public string SubCategory {get;set;}
      public int Page {get;set;}
      public int Size {get;set;}
      /* Has Properties */
      public bool HasCategory { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Category); } }
      // etc...
 }
```

Then I use a library called PagedList from NuGet, but you could write your own query with whatever ORM or non-ORM you have. Then I write a nice little extension method to check if a category or sub category exists.

```
 /* I'm using EF ish code, but plug in your stuff here */
 public ActionResult Index(SearchModel search) {
    var results = Db.Certifications
                    .If(search.HasCategory, q => q.Where(x => x.Category == search.Category)
                    .If(search.HasSubCategory, q => q.Where(x => x.SubCategory == search.SubCategory)
                    .If(search.HasSort, q => q.OrderBy(/* whatever */)
                    .ToPagedList(page: search.Page, size: search.Size);

      return View(result);
 }
```

Super simple solution and nothing really getting in your way.

**This is a really simple problem to solve, so don't lean on anything too heavy that might constrain you or frustrate you later.**